# Problem Customizing the Navigation Menu from Silverlight Business Application

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, menu, navigation

I'm using the Silverlight Business Application Template but I need to customize the MainPage layout to match the client's existing ASP.NET projects pattern. I was able to create the Navigation menu which highlights the selected item. But when a MouseEnter event occurs, the selected menu item's style becomes that of MouseOver VisualState. And on MouseLeave, the selected menu item turns to Normal VisualState. This behavior worked for the solution's default menu but something may be missing from my modification. The code definition are as follows. Thanks!

```xml
<Style x:Key="NavMenuItem" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,10,20,10" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="150"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                <Grid Margin="20,20,0,0">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.01" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MenuItemBorder" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.01" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MenuItemBorder" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.01" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MenuItemBorder" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LinkStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="InactiveLink"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ActiveLink">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.01" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MenuItemBorder" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border Name="MenuItemBorder" CornerRadius="10,0,0,10" Opacity="0" 
                            MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}">
                        <!--BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1"-->
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5, 0" EndPoint="0.5, 1">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.6"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Silver" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="BorderShadow" ShadowDepth="5" Color="#FF484848" Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="5"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```xml
            <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource NavMenuItem}" NavigateUri="/Home" TargetName="ContentFrame" 
                             MouseEnter="HyperlinkButton_MouseEnterLeave" MouseLeave="HyperlinkButton_MouseEnterLeave" />
```

```cs
    private void HyperlinkButton_MouseEnterLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        HyperlinkButton hb = sender as HyperlinkButton;
        if (hb.NavigateUri.ToString() == ContentFrame.CurrentSource.ToString())
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "ActiveLink", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try to set the MouseOver VisualSatate of your button on the EventHandler if it Event is MouseEnter and reset it if it is a MouseLeave Event.

And i think i would set up two event handlers and not only one for both events, then you can easily set the MouseOver state and the ActiveState too.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. I actually want the selected menu to stay on ActiveLink VisualState when the mouse enters or leaves. But the current behavior is the selected menu changes to MouseOver VisualState on MouseEnter, then changes to Normal VisualState on MouseLeave. It seems the client behavior overrides the VisualState that I set from the code behind.

Comment: Oh now finally i understand your question. :)

Comment: It's ok. :) And for me it is even harder because my English is not my native Language. I'm guessing that both storyboards start for your button and the ActiveLink finishes first and then finishes the MouseLeave and maybe because of that it goes back to Normal state. You could try to expand the storyboards time period and look how they actually run.

Comment: I tried increasing the ActiveLink duration to 0.05 seconds but the result is still the same. Btw, LinkState is not part of standard ViewStateGroups for HyperlinkButton, and it's only set with the following code:

Comment: Yes i saw that from your code and XAML, wild guess would be to remove the normal and MouseOver visualstates from the CommonStates group and add them your linkstates and then change them manually from your event handler. That's the best i can come up with now, but i take a quick look into it

Comment: private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
       foreach (UIElement child in LinksStackPanel.Children) {
                HyperlinkButton hb = child as HyperlinkButton;
                if (hb != null && hb.NavigateUri != null) {
                    if (hb.NavigateUri.ToString().Equals(e.Uri.ToString())) {
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "ActiveLink", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "InactiveLink", true);
                    }
                }
        }
}

Comment: Your last suggestion worked for me. Thank you very much for your help! :)